# Show GPU frequencies in Conky

Tags: gpu, conky, system-monitoring

I want to show 3 GPU clocks on Conky. I can only find sources online to display one. The Graphics Clock, But as shown in my picture, there's a memory clock, and a processor clock that I'd like to add as well.. Does anyone know the name of the object I have to use to get these 2 items. Here's the line of code for the Graphics clock

`Graphics Clock${alignr}${execi 1 nvidia-settings -query GPUCurrentClockFreqs | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCurrentClockFreqs.*?: (\d+)./;'}MHz`

I know I have to replace GPUCurrentClockFreqs with something, but I can't find out what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvidia-settings -query all` will list all parameters. Run `nvidia-settings -query all|grep Freq` or `nvidia-settings -query all|grep Clock` in a terminal and post here the result. Some of the parameters printed by those commands should help you. I don't have a nvidia gpu so I cannot run it myself

Edit:
For the CPU frequency, you can get it through other means:

- /proc/cpuinfo contains information for each core of your cpu

  You can run something like `cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep -m 1 -i mhz|cut -d: -f 2|cut -c 2-` and this will output the current frequency of the first core of your CPU.
- The `cpufreq-info` command shows more frequency-related information, but it may not be installed on your system. Check your distro's package manager for a package named `cpufreq-utils` or something similar.

  You can run `cpufreq-info |grep 'current CPU frequency'|cut -d' ' -f 7|head -n 1`, and this will show you the current frequency of the first core

Comment: Thank you, this was actually very useful. Unfortunately, I still wasn't able to find the key word I wanted. I tried to grep words like mem, clock, GPU, Curr, and ended up with nothing. There MUST be a way to access this information. I mean the Nvidia-Settings GUI gets it somehow!

Comment: `grep` is case-sensitive. If you do `grep clock` you won't get anything. Either use `grep Clock` or `grep -i clock` [the `-i` switch makes it case-insensitive]. Also, `nvidia-settings -query all|grep Clock` should at least show the value of GPUCurrentClockFreqs

Comment: Sorry for the misleading comment. I meant I got nothing specific to the memory, and processor clocks. I got results in general, but thank you :)

Comment: Well… You can get the CPU and the RAM clocks from other sources. For the CPU, you can do `cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep -i mhz`. This will output a line for each core of your CPU. For the RAM, I don't know where you can get it from. You should create a new question, 'How can I get my RAM frequency?' or something similar. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: Forget I said that, I'm just thinking in the wrong spot. I know the numbers in Powermizer Information are related to GPU clocks, and not my CPU and RAM.

Comment: Then what would "Processor Clock" refer to, if not the frequency of your CPU? I haven't used PowerMizer so I do not know anything about it. You can also run a simple test: Open PowerMizer and a terminal, run one of the commands in my answer to get the current CPU frequency and compare it to what PowerMizer is saying

Comment: I was able to get the Processor clock to mimmic the powermizer setting, the keyword was `GPUCurrentProcessorClockFreqs`

the keyword for Graphic Clock was `GPUCurrentClockFreqs` I'm not sure what the difference is, but they don't refer to my CPU as that freq is a seperate number. Now the only one I have to do is the memory one.

Comment: Intuition says that the keyword for memory is `GPUCurrentMemoryClockFreqs`. Try doing `nvidia-settings -query all|grep Memory`

Comment: Yes, I tried that one. I think I'm on the right track with this, it's just a matter of finding the right word with Grep. I'll mark your answer as the solution since it led me to my working results. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks. You can also try `nvidia-settings -query all|grep -i mem`. From what I have read [elsewhere](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-gpu-info), you can install `nvclock` and run `nvclock -i` to get some information about your GPU

Comment: why nvidia memfreq only show half of the real Mhz value?